# How to translate front but keep admin in FR

Tags: i18n-l10n, 9

I have a website with translation by domain, ex :

- monsite.fr
- fr.monsite.ca
- en.moniste.ca
  ...

But in admin i'd like to stay on monsite.fr/admin whatever content that i translate, is it possible ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have the following core multilingual modules enable

- Interface Translation (`locale`)
- Language (`language`)

I'll assume you have also added your desired languages on `/admin/config/regional/language`

On the `/admin/config/regional/language/detection` page you can set the language preference used by your site.

You will want to enable:

- Account administration pages [X]
- User [X]

Then under the admin account edit page, you can find `LANGUAGE SETTINGS | Administration pages language`. You will want to set this to your preference.

Answer (score 0):

@tyler36 :
thanks for your answer, i've done all this config but when i' m on admin content page when i click on translate i'm redirected to an other domain.
Below my config detection url by domain (/admin/config/regional/language/detection/url) :

- FR : site.fr
- IT : site.it
- CA-EN : en.site.ca
- CA-FR : fr.site.ca....
  when i want to translate a french page to italian when i click on the language i'm redirected to this edit page on dedicated domain BUT i want to stay on french admin BO whatever translation, is it clear ? :)
  is it possible ?

Regards